# How can I use a custom tensorflow model with the CV2 DNN module?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv

I retrained an object detection model based on Google's Tensorflow object detection API. I exported it as a frozen inference graph. I would like to use it with CV2's DNN module:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(URL)

cvNet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('graph.pb', 'graph.pbtxt')

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    rows = img.shape[0]
    cols = img.shape[1]
    cvNet.setInput(cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1.0/127.5, (300, 300), (127.5, 127.5, 127.5), swapRB=True, crop=False))
    cvOut = cv2Net.forward()

    for detection in cv2Out[0,0,:,:]:
        score = float(detection[2])
        if score > 0.3:
            left = detection[3] * cols
            top = detection[4] * rows
            right = detection[5] * cols
            bottom = detection[6] * rows
            cv2.rectangle(img, (int(left), int(top)), (int(right), int(bottom)), (23, 230, 210), thickness=2)
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) ==27:
        exit(0)
```

I get this error: `Const input blob for weights not found in function getConstBlob`

From my research, I believe I have to optimize the inference graph. I can't find any documentation as how to do this.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: in which line are you getting this error?

Comment: I came across [this blog post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/11/object-detection-with-deep-learning-and-opencv/) but it is specific to pretrained caffe model. Hope you can find something useful out of it!

Comment: @JeruLuke `cvNet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('graph.pb', 'graph.pbtxt')` caused the error. The link you posted is also the guide I was somewhat working off of, I just wanted to use tensorflow instead of a caffe model.